# Sending a link through smtplib and python

Tags: python-3.x, sms, smtplib

I am using smtplib to send text messages as alerts to my phone for a certain event on a website. I have all the webscraping figured out, but when I attach the link I want sent in the text message, it just freaks out and sends a blank message. Any ideas? Thanks. Here is my current message:

```
msg = "Reservations open! https://mvascheduling.mva.maryland.gov/Default.aspx"
```

Answer (score 0):

So I did some more digging and it seems it's an internal reading error on the mail server's side. This seemed to work.

```
msg = "Reservations open!" + "\nhttps://mvascheduling.mva.maryland.gov/Default.aspx"
```

Adding a new line fixes the read issues with a message header. The more you know.